# How to identify click event on image which is present inside group? I want to identify click event at the time of rendering json

Tags: fabricjs

I am not able to identify click event on object which present inside the group at the time of rendering the json.

```
add = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 200, height: 100, left: 10, top: 10, angle: 0, stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 0.2,
  fill: 'white'
});

var group = new fabric.Group([add], {
  relationid: countsub,
  objecttype: 'Subnet',
  subTargetCheck: true,
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  angle: 0
});
this.canvas.add(group);
fabric.Image.fromURL('assets/images/AWS@2x.png', function(oImg) {
  oImg.set({
    id: 'img',
    left: 5,
    top: 5,
    selectable: true,
    hasBorders: false,
    hasControls: false,
    hasRotatingPoint: false,
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  });
  oImg.scaleToWidth(25);
  oImg.scaleToHeight(15);
  group.addWithUpdate(oImg);
});
```

I want to know is there any way to know click on the image which is part of one group.here image is 'assets/images/AWS@2x.png'

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely right, `subTargetCheck: true` is the way to go. Then you just attach an appropriate event listener (`mousedown` if you want to detect a click) to your group and check the `subTargets` property of the event. It contains an array of sub-targets, if any:

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

const add = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 200, height: 100, left: 10, top: 10, angle: 0, stroke: 'black',
  fill: 'white'
});

const group = new fabric.Group([add], {
  subTargetCheck: true,
  left: 20,
  top: 20,
});
canvas.add(group);
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://via.placeholder.com/50x50', (oImg) => {
  oImg.set({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
  });
  group.addWithUpdate(oImg);
  canvas.requestRenderAll();
});

group.on('mousedown', (e) => {
  if (e.subTargets[0] && e.subTargets[0].type === 'image') {
    console.log('clicked on image')
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: ivory;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="250" height="200"></canvas>
```